# Retrieve error message from MS SQL to QTP

Tags: sql-server, testing, automated-tests, qtp, hp-uft

I have to load files to MS SQL using stored procedure:

```
exec [database].[dbo].[tablename]  @FullFilePath = 'fullpathtofile'
```

Files are big and loading may last several minutes up to 40 minutes. UFT returns 'timeout' error in 20-30 seconds.
Need help to make UFT wait until files are loaded. Fixed `wait()` doesn't make sense, because I do not know how long exactly it may take.

`For each objError in dbConnectionChargebacks.Errors` gives me messages (like 50000 as loading error or 3105 as fileID for successful load). But it works only when file is loaded in <20 seconds. For big files, I don't know how to wait for that)

Comment: I'd consider calling the stored procedure from a batch file rather than directly from UFT.  You can execute the batch file and let UFT wait till it completes before you carry on, and the batch file won't complete until the stored procedure does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with @Dave. store your procedures in a batch file and using Wscript object, you can execute that file

```
Set Wsc = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
intReturn = Wsc.Run("cmd /c " & PathofbatchFile, 1 True) 'true will wait until batch file returns completion code
```

0 is the return code for success.

Comment: Thanks Dave and @Mithilesh. Working on that.
Now I have another problem ) Is it possible to pass variables from qtp to batch to run sql queries? I need current directory and current date to be passed, and maybe some other dynamic variables

Comment: Or, other option - if I open sql file via batch file, will qtp still wait enough?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/631f064e-9e72-4736-8b3d-2773a4ec1271/how-can-i-pass-parameters-to-a-batch-file-from-qtp-script?forum=softwaretesting